# Merging Overlapping DNA segments into 1 complete segment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Did this challenge for an employer (not under an NDA or anything) for a junior python-related position and wasn't selected. Unfortunately they couldn't offer feedback, and as this was my first stab at doing something in python, I really have no idea if maybe I missed something and it's not totally correct, or maybe it doesn't follow best practices in concern to Python. My overall runtime did end up being \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ but couldn't think of a way to improve it. Anyways, I would appreciate any sort of feedback.

Challenge:

> 1. The input is at most 50 DNA sequences (i.e, the character set is limited to T/C/G/A) whose length does not exceed 1000 characters.
> 2. The sequences are given in FASTA format. These sequences are all different fragments of one chromosome.
> 3. The specific set of sequences you will get satisfy a very unique property:  there exists a unique way to reconstruct the entire chromosome from these reads by gluing together pairs of reads that overlap by more than half their length. An example set of input strings is attached.
> 4. The output of your program should be this unique sequence that contains each of the given input strings as a substring.

My overall approach (assuming no redundant DNA segments) is to start off with a random sequence A and find other sequences containing A[0-X] that also overlap with sequence A. As I overlap, A[0-X] will keep changing. Once A[0-X] stops changing, I switch over to the other side of A and do the same thing.

Pseudocode of algorithm:

> ```
> Start off with a random sequence A and find other sequences containing A[0-X]. 
>
> Go through the list of sequences one by one 
>   If a sequence B contains substring A[0-X]
>       Check for an overlap on the left end of sequence B
>             if there's an overlap combine the sequences
>           Re-assign new A[0-X]
>   A[0-X] hasn't changed? switch to other end of the sequence (looking at A[length-X, length])
> ```

At this point (built off of two ends as far as I can go) I know I have the entire piece, so leftover segments would just be enveloped completely.

Main function:

```py
X = 10 # the length we're testing

def main(): 
    # prompt user to open file 
    filename = input("Enter filename with same format as example.txt\n")

    # try to open file and read it's contents
    sequences = readFile(filename)    

    # if we succeeded
    if sequences != None:

        # build off of one sequence
        checkSequence = sequences[0]
        del sequences[0] # delete it from list 

        # build off of left end of checkSequence
        checkSequence, sequences = buildAlgorithm(checkSequence, sequences, 0) # print(len(sequences))
        # build off of right end of checkSequence
        checkSequence, sequences = buildAlgorithm(checkSequence, sequences, 1) # print(len(sequences))

        # write final sequence to file      
        fileCheckSequence = open('output.txt', 'w')
        fileCheckSequence.write(checkSequence)
        fileCheckSequence.close()

        # write leftovers to file as well
        fileCheckList = open('leftovers.txt', 'w')
        for val in sequences:
            fileCheckList.write(val)
            fileCheckList.write("\n")
        fileCheckSequence.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Main work:

```py
"""
Facilitates the search and adding on of sequences
Input:
    checkSequence: Total sequence so far
    sequences: list of sequences not used yet
    flag: 0-> build off right end 1->build off left end
Output: 
    checkSequence, sequences 
"""
def buildAlgorithm(checkSequence, sequences, flag):
    if flag == 0:
        keySequence = checkSequence[:X] # grab first 10 characters
    else:
        keySequence = checkSequence[-X:] # grab last 10 characters
    # reverse for convenience, puts search value at 0 
    reverseKey = keySequence[::-1] # extended slice O(len(slice))

    idx = 0 # counter for list of sequences
    i = X-1 # counter for each individual sequence

    # Go through and check for a matching sequence
    while idx < len(sequences):
        val = sequences[idx]
        while i < len(val): # Not Boyer Moore, but has the whole word shift , grows O(n)
            # start comparing at the Xth letter of sequence
            cs = val[i] 
            ks = reverseKey[0] # end value of keySequence
            # compare two letters
            if cs == ks: 
                # if they match, compare entire chunks
                if compareTwoSequences(val, reverseKey, i): # grows O(n)
                    beforeSequence = keySequence
                    """
                    double check they can fit together, then compare
                    right or left chunk depending on if we're building 
                    off right or left ends
                    """
                    if flag == 0: # compare right part of sequence
                        if compareOverlap(checkSequence, val, i, 0): # grows O(n)
                            checkSequence = overlapSequences(checkSequence, val, i, 0)
                            keySequence = checkSequence[:X] # new keySequence
                            del sequences[idx] # delete that sequence
                            idx = 0 
                            # it means we didn't accomplish anything, we're done
                            if beforeSequence == keySequence:
                                return checkSequence, sequences
                            else:
                                reverseKey = keySequence[::-1]
                    else: # compare left part of sequence
                        if compareOverlap(checkSequence, val, i, 1): # grows O(n)
                            checkSequence = overlapSequences(checkSequence, val, i, 1)
                            keySequence = checkSequence[-X:] # new keySequence
                            del sequences[idx] # delete that sequence
                            idx = 0 # start idx back to 0
                            # don't need to do it this time around
                            reverseKey = keySequence[::-1]                  
            else:
                # if not, check if cs is in subsequence at all 
                if not checkCs(reverseKey, cs):
                    i+=10 # skip over 10 spaces
            i+=1
        i = X-1 # reset position of i
        idx+=1 # evaluate next sequence 
    return checkSequence, sequences
```

The rest of the functions:

```py
"""
Checks whether a character exists within a given sequence
Input: 
    keySequence: given sequence
    cs: character to search for 
Output: 
    True (character exists within sequence), False (character DNE within  sequence)
"""
def checkCs(keySequence, cs):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(keySequence):
        if cs == keySequence[idx]:
            return True
        idx+=1
    #if we got here, cs isn't in keySequence
    return False

"""
Checks whether a given sequence exists in a longer sequence 
Input: 
    checkSequence: longer sequence
    reverseKey: short sequence who's length dictates X
    i: index from where to start on longer sequence
Output: 
    True (they match), False (they do not match)
"""
def compareTwoSequences(checkSequence, reverseKey, i):
    cs = checkSequence[i]
    ks = reverseKey[0]

    idx = 0

    # compare starting from i and 0
    while idx < len(reverseKey):
        cs = checkSequence[i]
        ks = reverseKey[idx]
        if cs != ks:
            return False
        else:
            idx+=1
            i-=1

    # if we made it here, they match
    return True

"""
Checks if a beginning or end chunk of a shorter sequence exists in a longer     sequence
Input: 
    checkSequence: longer sequence
    valSequence: shorter sequence
    i: index of starting position for shorter sequence
    flag: 0 (check beginning), 1 (check end)
Output:
    True (they math), False (they do not match)
"""
def compareOverlap(checkSequence, valSequence, i, flag):
    idx = i
    # compare forward
    if flag == 0:
        idx1 = X-1
        while idx < len(valSequence):
            if valSequence[idx] != checkSequence[idx1]:
                return False
            idx+=1
            idx1+=1     
    # compare backward
    else:
        idx1 = len(checkSequence) - 1
        while idx > 0:
            if valSequence[idx] != checkSequence[idx1]:
                return False
            idx-=1
            idx1-=1
    return True

"""
Combined two sequences where they overlap
Input: 
    checkSequence: original sequence 
    val: smaller sequence that will be added to checkSequence
    i: index of val, where overlap starts
    flag: 0 (overlap forwards), 1 (overlap backwards)
Output: 
    new compiled sequence
"""
def overlapSequences(checkSequence, val, i, flag):
    sequenceChunk = ""
    # overlap forward
    if flag == 0:
        idx = 0
        while idx < i-9:
            sequenceChunk = sequenceChunk + val[idx]
            idx+=1
        checkSequence = sequenceChunk + checkSequence
    # overlap backwards
    else:
        idx = i+1
        while idx < len(val):
            sequenceChunk = sequenceChunk + val[idx]
            idx+=1
        checkSequence = checkSequence + sequenceChunk
    return checkSequence

"""
Reads in file to extract sequences and input them into a list
Input: filename
Output: list of sequences or error
"""
def readFile(filename):
    try:
        in_file = open(filename + ".txt", "r")
        print ("File opened successfully\n")

        line = in_file.readline() #read in first line of file
        sequenceBlock = "" # container for sequence
        sequences = [] # list for sequence blocks, 50 of them this time around

        while line:
            # if we hit >Rosalind_#### line
            if line[0] == ">":
                # make sure there's something to store
                if sequenceBlock:
                    # print("sequence block: " + sequenceBlock + "\n")
                    sequences.append(sequenceBlock) 
                    sequenceBlock = "" # reset block
            # else just add it to the sequence block
            else:
                sequenceBlock = sequenceBlock + line
            # get the next line
            line = in_file.readline().rstrip() # get rid of any trailing whitespaces

        # add in the last sequence
        sequences.append(sequenceBlock)

        # when we're done, return this list
        return sequences
        in_file.close()
    except IOError:
        print("Cannot open file! See example.txt\n")
        return None
```

Answer (score 2):

I think primarily refactoring and readability are the issues here. It's quite hard to read what's going on here. In part, that's because you're doing a complex algorithm, but there's a lot more you could be doing to help people follow what your code does.

You have excessively long functions. `buildAlgorithm` is the entire algorithm in one function. Ideally, each function would have one specific job to do. Even if each function you write is only used once, it's worthwhile. Having a collection of smaller functions allows you to test easier, make changes easier and extend functionality.

However you definitely have repeat code. Your sequence comparisons should be a function. This isn't the right syntax, but you should refactor to something like this:

```
def compare():
    checkSequence = overlapSequences(checkSequence, val, i, 0)
    keySequence = checkSequence[:X] # new keySequence
    del sequences[idx] # delete that sequence
    idx = 0 
    # it means we didn't accomplish anything, we're done
    if beforeSequence == keySequence:
        return checkSequence, sequences
    else:
        reverseKey = keySequence[::-1]
```

Which could then be called like this:

```
if flag == 0: # compare right part of sequence
    if compareOverlap(checkSequence, val, i, 0): # grows O(n)
        compare()
else:
    if compareOverlap(checkSequence, val, i, 1): # grows O(n)
        compare(reverse=True)
```

This makes code much more readable too. You tend to use a lot of comments, but good function names and refactoring would help readability much more. As would good variable names. Part of why I didn't try to make your function valid is I would've needed to try discern what `val`, `i`, `X` and `idx` were. All names that mean practically the same thing, and tell me nothing about their use.

```
X = 10 # the length we're testing
```

Should be

```
TEST_LENGTH = 10
```

Now you don't need a comment, and every time this value is used you'll have a clearer understanding of what it's meant to be.